# Использование камеры как службы

Tags: камера, android

Дарова всем!

Я пишу приложение под андроид, которое в фоновом режиме должен делать снимки с фронтальной камеры и обрабатывать их.

Проблема в том, что метод который получает снимки с камеры не вызывается, точнее метод `TakePicture`

Поискал в интернете но конкретного решения данной проблемы не нашел

Может я не смог донести свои мысли, поэтому прикрепляю ссылку, где юзеры искали выход из данной ситуации - [`Android Camera without Preview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/).

В `Google Play` можно найти приложение с названием `Hold Screen On` в этом приложении разработчики смогли решить данную проблему.

Может, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: нужно больше кода!
выложите свой код, где вызывается TakePicture

Comment: Спонсирую этот вопрос на 500 репутации за решение с помощью SDK (не NDK).

Comment: Есть большое подозрение, что разработчики Hold Screen On как раз решили задачу с привлечением ndk.